# Somebody stole my nic

Tags: support, display-names

I just noticed that somebody else is using the name "duffymo" on Stackoverflow.  They just signed up today.

The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413976/how-to-search-usenet-for-programming-questions-closed).

If this is indicative of the kind of question this person will be asking, I'm worried that people will confuse him/her with me.  I can develop a bad rep on my own, thank you.

Is there any way to delete this ID before they make me look like a big, fat eejit?  Thanks.

Comment: Too late, man. Did you see that "question"?

Comment: So you're saying you don't want to know "How to search usenet for programming questions?"

Comment: From the title I thought someone stole your network card!

Comment: ...how do we know that you are the *real* duffymo!?

Comment: Uh....I've got a note from my mommy.  Will that do?

Answer (score 5):

If he starts using your gravatar, *vee vill fiya ze lezars!* :)

Comment: Will you be talking in a fake accent while you are doing that?

Comment: Actually I'd be speaking with a real accent, just not my own ;)

Answer (score 4):

There is no requirement that user names be unique so I don't think it would be fair to delete the ID on *that* basis (there may be *other* reasons, though). Unless you feel that there is some sort of abuse or fraud that goes with the name choice, I don't think you have a case.

But you are free to change your name to something else.

Personally, I wouldn't worry about it at this point. You have no indication that this user is going to establish any sort of lasting presence on the system... and your Gravatars are unique.

Comment: This is obviously aimed at the original duffymo in some way. If it happens again, I would talk to the moderators about it.

Comment: Agreed. If there is some sort of abuse or fraud that goes with the name choice, I *would* consider that grounds for action. Adding that to my answer.

Comment: "But you are free to change your name to something else." - not an option, unless you're telling me that Robert C. Cartaino is available.     I was duffymo first.  S/he ought to give it up, not me.